# How to manually insert a breakpoint that Bochs's built-in debugger will stop at? INT3 doesn't work

Tags: debugging, x86, x86-16, bochs

I am using `bochs` enhanced debugger (`bochs` debugger with gui), but it's also debugging the BIOS code, and this is too complicated for me. So how can I set a breakpoint manually at the start of my code?

I tried `int3` but it doesn't stop on it.

Comment: What does "not working" mean exactly? What happens instead?

Comment: it continues the execution without pausing

Comment: i have deleted the image file and recompiled it to make sure it runs with int3 . i am using bochs with gui so i can't set a breakpoint from the command line , and it's nearly impossible to set a breakpoint with the gui at the start of my code because the gui shows minimal number of addresses .

Answer (score 5, accepted):

[The osdev wiki](https://wiki.osdev.org/Bochs#Magic_Breakpoint) describes the key features:

> ##### Magic Breakpoint
>
> When you're using Bochs with the internal debugger, you can trigger the debugger via a facility called magic breakpoints. To trigger a breakpoint, you can insert **`xchg bx, bx`** (in GAS syntax, `xchgw %bx, %bx`) anywhere in the code and Bochs will trap into the debugger as soon as it executes it. On real hardware this has no effect as it merely replaces the BX register with itself.
>
> You should put the following line in your **Bochs configuration file** to have it listen to magic breakpoints:
>
> ```
> magic_break: enabled=1
> ```

Presumably Bochs doesn't trap `int3` because normal guest code might be using it.  (e.g. if you're using Bochs to debug a debugger or a kernel with debug facilities, you'd want to follow how `int3` is handled in the guest, not have Bochs eat it.)

---

Apparently there's also an [I/O debug-breakpoint](https://wiki.osdev.org/Bochs#I.2FO_debugger_macros) mechanism using the `out` instruction to output two words to a special port number, `0x8A00`, so you can get Bochs to break that way without making it break on `xchg bx,bx`.  The `xchg` way is definitely easier to use (less intrusive; drop-in NOP with no register setup needed) and more compact.  OSdev.org uses C to describe what to output:

```
 //outputs a character to the debug console
 #define BochsConsolePrintChar(c) outportb(0xe9, c)
 //stops simulation and breaks into the debug console
 #define BochsBreak() outportw(0x8A00,0x8A00); outportw(0x8A00,0x08AE0);
```